# Pushing data into array destroys previous data

Tags: javascript

So my situation here is that I would like to take data from a Javascript Object which is:

```
{
  "task": {
    "task-1": {
      "job": "Engineer"
    },
    "task-2": {
      "job": "Developer"
    }
  }
}
```

and convert that to

```
{
  {
    "id": 1,
    "job": "Engineer"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "job": "Developer"
  },
}
```

I was successful in converting it but when I execute the `.push()`, it only pushes the `Developer` job, not the `Engineer` job, e.g:

```
{
  {
    "id": 2,
    "job": "Developer"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "job": "Developer"
  }
}
```

Here is the code that I am using.

```
var jobs = { "task": { "task-1": { "job": "Engineer" }, "task-2": { "job": "Developer" } } };
var jobSchema = { 'id': '', 'job': '' };
var currentJobs = [];

var i = 0;
var curJobs = jobs.task;
for (var task in curJobs) {
  if (curJobs.hasOwnProperty(task)) {
    i++;
    jobSchema.id = i;
    jobSchema.job = curJobs[task].job;
    currentJobs.push(jobSchema);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are repeatedly modifying the same instance and pushing it into your array. Nothing is getting 'destroyed', you just never make new instances to push.

Comment: Oh so how do I not make it modify the same instance?

Comment: make a new instance and modify that? you can just stick a jobSchema = {} after i++

Comment: Cheers for that, if you want to submit an answer I'll accept it for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
var jobSchema = { 'id': '', 'job': '' };
```

makes a new instance of an object which you then modify in the loop and push into the array. The problem is it's the same instance every time - all you end up with is an array of references to the same instance. While this code could be simplified and cleaned up further, a minimally invasive solution is to just add

```
jobSchema = {};
```

At the beginning of the body of your loop.

Comment: Thanks for that, it works. I'll accept when I can. :)